# how to make vertically collection view with center point

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionview

I want to make vertically collection view with one label per row and must be center line to Scroll and select center point like this please guide me thanks
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQ4ym.jpg

```
extension ViewController : UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource
{
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return tempArray.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "myCell", for: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell
        cell.lblNumber.text = "\(indexPath.row)"
        return cell
```

Comment: Looks like you can use https://codewithchris.com/uipickerview-example/, UIPickerView to solve the issue instead of UICollectionView

Comment: Opps i forget picker view thank u my bro